# Liquibase How to escape Changelog Property Substitution

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-sql

Is it possible to escape the Liquibase [Changelog Property Substitution](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changelog-property-substitution.html)?

This is my Changeset:

```
<changeSet author="me" id="changeSetOne">
    <sql>
        INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (VALUE, DESCRIPTION) VALUES (
            '${ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}/some/path/',
            'describe nothing');
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

The result, with (*ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE* = "C:/foo"):

```
+-----------------+----------------+
|VALUE            |DESCRIPTION     |
+-----------------+----------------+
|C:/foo/some/path/|describe nothing|
+-----------------+----------------+
```

But I don't want to replace this placeholder by Liquibase, so my result should look like this:

```
+----------------------------------+----------------+
|VALUE                             |DESCRIPTION     |
+----------------------------------+----------------+
|${ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}/some/path/|describe nothing|
+----------------------------------+----------------+
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: Have you tried the value as is?  I thought forward slash doesn't need escaping.  Or you could try setting ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE = "C:\/foo"

Answer (score 0):

What you seek is a hack or a way to escape (eg: `\${ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}` or `$${ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}`).

I don't know if this particular issue relate to that: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1023 but until someone fix it, you will have to use this awesome hack™:

```
<property name="dollar" value="$" />

<update tableName="THE_TABLE">
  <column name="THE_COLUMN" value="${dollar}{ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}" />
</update>
```

Then, when liquibase see `${dollar}{ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}`, it should replace it with `${ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}`.